# Как повторять звук уведомления Notification

Tags: java, android, android-notification

При нажатии на item в listview у меня выскакивает Notification(уведомление). Как мне сделать так, чтобы звук уведомления повторялось каждых 5 минут, пока пользователь не уберет это уведомление? Вот код метода onItemClick()

```
    listtime.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String value = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), "M_CH_ID");

            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentTitle("У Вас скоро автобус!")
                    .setContentText(value)
                    .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                    .setSound(uri);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Стандартного способа сделать так, боюсь, нет. Проще всего для этого будет использовать `AlarmManager`.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html Этот класс содержит множество методов для отсроченного выполнения кода.